# How to give a div with display: table-cell a percentage height?

Tags: html, css

Now I'm working on a card game and now I'm writing code about the hand cards.
Our target should be like (and it's my codes' result in IE10)
  [image: Target]
There are three requirements:
1. All cards will fill the hand cards region.
2. All cards have same width.
3. If there are too many cards, the right one will be on the left one. (The card with blue border is the leftest, it's below the second one)
So we decided to use table to do it. Here are the codes.

```
<style>
    .hand {
        position: absolute; /* We need to locate it */
        display: table;
        width: 60%;
        height: 15%;
        left: 19.5%;
    }
        .hand .wrap {
            position: relative;
            display: table-cell;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .hand .card {
            position: relative;
            left: 50%;
        }
</style>
<div style="width: 400px; height:100px; position: relative"> 
<!-- Container's width and height will change with JavaScript -->
    <div class="hand">
        <div class="wrap">
            <img class="card" src=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap">
            <img class="card" src=""/>
        </div>
        <!-- More cards can be added using JavaScript. -->
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function adjust() { // Run this function when inserting new cards.
        $(".hand .card").css("margin-left", function () {
            return 0 - $(this).width() / 2 + "px";
        });
    }
</script>
```

Now, the codes' result in IE10 is on the above, **but in Firefox and Chrome, the `.hand`'s height is same as the height of image in `.card`.**
I had read some other similar questions and now I know CSS `height` property on table doesn't effect, and I fellow one of the solution to set `.card` as `position: absolute;`,  but it only works in Chrome, in IE10 the `.card`s now has 0px width and height, in Firefox they all at the center of `.hand`.
So is there any Cross-Browser solution to set the height or any other way to do it?
Thanks very much!

Comment: `If there are too many cards, the right one will be on the left one.`  What?

Comment: @Leng As the pic shows, the right part of the first card is covered by the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation doesn't work because you cannot apply `position` to a table cell (or an element that behaves like one). You need an extra markup element to allow for this.

Working sample, without any Javascript, should work in all modern browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/VN3wx/

**CSS**

```
#hand {
    display:table;
    width:550px;
    height:210px;
}
.card {
    display:table-cell;
}
.card > div {
    position:absolute;
}
.card img {
    height:210px;
    width:150px;
}
```

Code can be somewhat cleaner of course but it's for illustration purposes  ;)

Comment: I only resize the image because the sample image I took was kinda large, and you can resize `#hand` at will and it will keep working.

Comment: Sorry for my two deletions. But I think in this code when I need to resize the container I also need to change `img`s width and height.